# Training of models fails repeatedly

Tags: azure, azureportal, microsoft-translator

I have been trying to run the training of the model on the portal and it seems to repeatedly fail since last Friday. Is there a reason the model fails while training? How do I find out the reason for the failure in the portal?

Comment: Could you follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/custom-translator/how-to-view-model-details#view-model-training-details) to find the failure details?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please reach out to the Custom Translator Support team at custommt@microsoft.com?  If you could supply us with the details of your model, we can determine the cause of the training failure.

Thanks,
Scott